In Oracle APEX, 23.1 How do I change the colour based on the value of the label on the xaxis?
I want to be able to have different colour x-Axis labels (tickLabels?) based on the value of the Lable -- EXPIRED would be Red, "> 40 Days" would be Green, etc
Used the following javascript
function(options) {
console.log(options); // Log the entire options object to the console for inspection
var colorMapping = {
    'EXPIRED': '#FF0000', // red
    '<10 Days': '#00FF00', // green
    '<50 Days': '#0000FF', // blue
    'N/A': '#FFFF00' // yellow
};

// Check if xaxis.categories is defined
if (options.xaxis && options.xaxis.categories) {
    var labelColors = options.xaxis.categories.map(function(category) {
        return colorMapping[category] || '#000000'; // default black if not mapped
    });

    // Ensure xaxis.labels is defined before modifying it
    if (!options.xaxis.labels) {
        options.xaxis.labels = {};
    }

    // Update tick labels with the corresponding colors
    options.xaxis.labels.style = Object.assign(options.xaxis.labels.style || {}, {
        colors: labelColors
    });

    // Optionally adjust tick labels if that property is more appropriate
    options.xaxis.tickPlacement = 'on';
    options.xaxis.labels = {
        style: {
            colors: labelColors
        }
    };
}

return options;

}
